# Очистка QVector, находящегося внутри структуры

Tags: c++, qt, память

Имеется структура вида:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    qint32 field1;
    qint32 field2;
    QVector<qint16> field3;
};
```

После использования объекта данной структуры необходимо очистить QVector. Каким образом это можно сделать? Сейчас на ум приходит только такое решение: объявить внутри структуры метод *clear()*, который будет обнулять поля структуры и вызывать соответствующий метод для очистки вектора:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    qint32 field1;
    qint32 field2;
    QVector<qint16> field3;

    void clear()
    {
        field1 = 0;
        field2 = 0;
        field3.clear();
    }
};
```

Comment: Можно обнулять каждое поле в отдельности (в структурах поля публичны), а можно добавить конструктор, который будет обнулять поля, и, таким образом, уже существующему объекту можно будет просто присвоить вновь созданный "с нуля" объект. Уточните Ваш вопрос пояснениями, поскольку за очевидностью ответов закрадывается сомнение, что спрашиваете Вы именно о них.

Comment: Объект структуры используется несколько раз. Соответственно после каждого использования нужно очищать вектор, потому что при каждом новом использовании в нем находится различное число элементов.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы храните в вашем векторе типы-значения, то отдельно ничего выдумывать не нужно: деструктор вашей структуры вызовет деструктор вектора, который в свою очередь сам разрушит объекты, в нём хранящиеся.